# Differential Path Search of a Block Cipher

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, camellia

[Camellia Design and Analysis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1e2c/f01396552ffe256d3e1ea568284124269a1f.pdf) document refers to a paper:

> [24] M. Matsui, "Differential Path Search of the Block
>   Cipher E2," (in Japanese), Technical report of IE-
>   ICE, ISEC99-19, pp.57-64, The Institute of Electronics, Information and Communication Engineers, 1999

Does someone know the algorithm presented in the above paper, as I couldn't find the paper. It will be great if someone can link to the paper or the portion containing algorithm contents.

Comment: @Biv I think the question asks us to find the paper or its content actually.

Comment: It's paywalled, but I think this is the right one: http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110003297502/en

Comment: Matsui and his collaborator wrote another paper on E2 in 1999, "Cryptanalysis of a Reduced Version of the Block Cipher E2" (available in proceedings of FSE) which may contain some of the same techniques. You can also try emailing Matsui and seeing if a non-Japanese version of the tech report is available.

Comment: @pg1989 actually it is in Japanese! I will look in the paper you mentioned, and update the question

Comment: Section 3.1 of [Shirai, Kanamaru, and Abe](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45661-9_10) is not the original source, but it's a more or less clear description of the method applied to Camellia. Note that today this kind of task would be done with a MILP solver much more easily and conveniently.

Comment: @SamuelNeves how MILP can be helpful for Fiestel Cipers, how to map the Xor of F function output and right half?

Comment: @SamuelNeves, MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Program)?

Comment: @kodlu yes MILP is Mixed Integer Linear Programming